# What's the meaning of "already computed partitions that can short-circuit the computation of a parent RDD"?

Tags: apache-spark, rdd, apache-spark-sql

The spark thesis(http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/Pubs/TechRpts/2014/EECS-2014-12.pdf) say as pic below
[image]

I don't understand "***What's the meaning of "already computed partitions that can short-circuit the computation of a parent RDD***"
Can you explain it to me and list one or two examples ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine that you have an RDD and you've called `cache()` or `persist()` on top of it to persist it in memory. After this you've run some action on top of this RDD which caused its computation and thus caching. But:

1. RDD might be too big to cache it at whole and some partitions of it would not be cached in memory. This way in the Spark console you see percentage of the RDD persisted
2. Spark cache is LRU which means some partitions of RDD might be evicted from memory in case the memory is needed for another RDD accessed after this one.

This way on the Figure 2.5 you see some partitions painted black, which means that they are already persisted and no additional computations to recalculate them is needed. Some RDDs might be cached at a whole, some partially.

This is what this phrase is telling you: `The boundaries of the stages are the shuffle operations required for wide dependencies, or any already computed partitions that can short-circuit the computation of a parent RDD. The scheduler then launches tasks to compute missing partitions from each stage until it has computed the target RDD`. This means that if some RDD's partitions are already computed they won't be recomputed again on your call and would act as a boundaries for scheduling. Figure 2.5 shows that "Stage 1" would be completely omitted as its computation results are already cached